# Получить ссылку с якорем через $_SERVER

Tags: php, get, uri

У меня есть главная страница с ссылкой-якорем #id и когда пытаюсь получить в if-e 
`$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` - получаю строку с адресом без #id. как получить ссылку вида страница + #id

Comment: Никак: #id вообще не передаётся на сервер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Якорь только для браузеров.
Якорь не передается на сервер и не будет виден в суперглобальном массиве `$_SERVER`.

Для получения якоря можно использовать javascript: `document.location.hash`.

Если очень нужно, после загрузки основной страницы отправьте запрос на сервер (ajax), где якорь document.location.hash передайте как один из параметров запроса в $_POST.

Но, так лучше не делать, потому что сервер не должен ничего знать о якоре, который должен использоваться только для браузерной навигации внутри страницы.